# directive only works inside another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i made a directive for filtering data. It uses scope: true and no transclusion. Somehow it only works inside an ng-switch. Maybe also other directives but i havent tried.

My html looks like this:

```
<my-filter source="{{foodArray}}" filter="reaction,category"> // source and filter are properties on the directive scope
    <div>
        <div class="span3">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in filters.reaction"> // filters property of directive scope
                <td><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.isChecked" data-ng-change="filterCtrl.filterList()"></td>
                <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="food in filteredData"> // filteredData object on the directive scope
                // interating through filteredData
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</my-filter>
```

here is my directive and its controller:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myFilter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            var filterCtrl = this;
            $scope.filters = {};
            filterCtrl.inputArray = [];

            filterCtrl.filterList = function() {
                /* some code where tmp array is created */

                $scope.filteredData = tmp;
            }   
        }],
        controllerAs: 'filterCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, filterCtrl) {
            filterCtrl.inputArray = angular.fromJson(attrs.source);
            scope.filteredData = filterCtrl.inputArray;

            // ...
        }   
    }
});
```

FilteredData and filters are property of the directives scope. Now when i remove the ng switch around it the data is empty. Also the scope.source property can be an array or  an object. When i remove the ng switch and give it an object as source it actually throws a syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.fromJson

Which it doesnt throw when i use an array.

Not sure what to make of this. If anybody had this problem before i would love to hear from you.

Comment: Provide your directive and controller code and review your code indentation please.

Comment: Fixed the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Where did you include the "MyDirective" directive in your template?

Comment: i changed the name it is the <my-filter></my-filter> directive

Comment: Hm, I dont get it. I cannot see a my-filter directive either. Please provide consistent code, where at lteast the name of the direcitve matches the name in the template.

Comment: Why not use the .filter() module rather than .directive()?

Comment: this would be easier to see what is happening with a sample demonstrating the problem in a plunker